# Sharing using FB.ui() Dialogs

Tags: reactjs

I want to integrate share functionality from facebook on my  site what is built on react js.

According to the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog , I have to use this:

```js
<script>
document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    display: 'popup',
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function(response){});
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share Dialog</div>
```

So, i made this:

```js
export default function App() {

  const shareFb = () => {
    FB.ui({
      display: 'popup',
      method: 'share',
      href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  }, function (response) {
  });
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={shareFb}>share</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

... but I get an error:

> FB is not defined

Question: how to solve the issue?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-banach-k95go?file=/src/App.js

Comment: have you included the fb sdk? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise `FB` variable like this

```
export default function App() {
  const shareFb = () => {
    window.FB.ui(
      {
        display: 'popup',
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
      },
      function (response) {}
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={shareFb}>share</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```